# Favor existing window of an active buffer when opening that file/buffer from a different window

Tags: vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface

I have a tab with the following window structure within:

```
________________________________
a                               |
                                |
               x                |
________________________________|
b                               | 
                                |
                                |
________________________________|
```

`x` is the cursor position.

`:ls` lists two buffers open on this tab: `Main.cpp` and `maininclude.h`

`Main.cpp` is visible on `a`, and `maininclude.h` is visible on `b`. From `a`, if I issue command `:find maininclude.h`, this buffer is (re)opened in `a`, even though it is currently activie/visible in `b`. That is, I end up having two views in two different windows of the same file that I would like to avoid.

Is there a way to favor/privilege the window in which a current buffer is active/visible so that a `:find` for that file/buffer issued from any window in the tab automatically goes to that window and places the cursor there? If that buffer is not active/visible in any window, then indeed that buffer should be made active in the window from which `:find` was issued from.

An animated gif example of what I am facing is provided [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOpqw.jpg), reproduced below:

[image]

---

Edit1: `set switchbuf=useopen` does not work.

See image gif [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ETwj.jpg), reproduced below:

[image]

Comment: `set switchbuf=useopen`

Comment: @Biggybi see edit in OP. `switchbuf` does not work

Comment: Then either `find` does not respect it or your config somehow disables it. I can't try rn. You should give a shot at `sb` or other commands.

Comment: @Biggybi I am indeed able tto confirm that `:sb filename` works with `switchbuf=useopen` as you mentioned -- moving to a previously existing window itself.

Comment: The only commands that respect `switchbuf` are listed in the help for the option. OTOH, If that is an acceptable answer to your question Tryer, please add an answer (or ask Biggybi too).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Done! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, `set switchbuf=useopen` does not work with `:find`. What this means is that if you `:find b` with cursor in `a`, then `b` will be opened in `a`'s window regardless of how `switchbuf` is set.

However, if from `a`, one issues `:sb b`, then indeed the focus shifts to `b` in the bottom window pane leaving `a` untouched.